# How to find what object called a context menu

Tags: c#, event-handling, contextmenu

I have assigned my menuIndexEdit context menue to my indexValidImage array of picture boxes. Everything works fine when I right click except I cant find how to determine which box that was right clicked on. Any information is helpfull.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < indexValidImage.Count; i++)
        {
            indexValidImage[i].ContextMenuStrip = menuIndexEdit;
        }

    private void menuIndexEdit_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If im not mistake you want something like this

```
private void menuIndexEdit_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (contextMenuStrip1.SourceControlis PictureBox)
    {
        string strname = ((PictureBox)contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl).Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't need to loop through the picture box array to find the matching picture box?

Comment: Thank you for the help. menuIndexEdit.SourceControl.Name is the line that gives me the name of the control that called I right clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

The `sender` parameter of the `menuIndexEdit_opening` method will be the object that triggered the event.

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example of how I would get the calling object name? Becasue when I tried to use .ToString() it gave me the context menu as the sender not the calling object.

Answer (score 1):

The `SourceControl` property of the `ContextMenuStrip`.